# select usage in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a select option to select and sort events based on categories/domains/eligiblity. I'm kinda stuck on how to implement it.

```
<%= form_tag refresh_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= select("category", "category_id", Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'Choose Category'}) %> 
  <%= select("domain", "domain_id", Domain.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'Choose Domain'}) %>
  <%= select("eligible", "eligible_id", Eligible.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'Choose Eligibility'}) %>
  <%=submit_tag "Refresh"%>
<% end %>
```

I want to do all jugglery inside refresh controller

```
class RefreshController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cat = Category.find(category.category_id)
    @events = @cat.events 
    ........
    ........
  end
end
```

How should I send parameters selected into the controller. Particularly my case. The select tag is so confusing. I want the actual id of categories to be sent rather than values.

Category has these attributes: 'name' and 'id'. Same is with domains and eligibility

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a relationship between "events" model and Category/Domain/Eligible models? You might want to post a little more code...

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You complained about some stuff but you didn't say exactly what is happening differently from what you expected. Are you not getting the params in the controller?

Comment: I think the syntax you are missing is `@events = Category.find(params[:category][:category_id])` but this assumes that you want @event to be filled with "Category" objects which doesn't appear to make sense.  however as others have said you don't give any information about your schema so it's really hard to know what you want.

Comment: Did you add the new params to the whitelist via strong parameters?

Comment: Hurrah! @MaxWilliams You're the man! :) It worked!

Comment: @MaxWilliams: I edited the post. Each category has_many_and_belongs_to event. Same is with eligibles and domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your schema looks like this (you don't say so it's hard to tell):

```
#fields: category_id, eligible_id, domain_id
class Event
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :eligible
  belongs_to :domain

class Category
  has_many :events

class Eligible
  has_many :events

class Domain
  has_many :events
```

Rails' .find method allows you to pass a {field1 => required_value, field2 => required_value} hash to conditions, so you can call it like so:

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {:category_id => 123, :eligible_id => 456, :domain_id => 789})
```

so if you had something like this in your parameters

```
params => {:events => {:category_id => 123, :eligible_id => 456, :domain_id => 789}}
```

you could just say

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => params[:events])
```

which is nice and clean.

This requires you to change your form like so:

```
<%= select("events", "category_id", ...
<%= select("events", "eligible_id", ...
<%= select("events", "domain_id", ...
```

However, if they didn't select any of these they'll come through as empty strings, which the conditions will specifically look for (whereas you actually just don't care about that criterion).  So, you can strip these out of the hash in params.

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => params[:events].reject{|k,v| v.blank?})
```